# Why is Jenkins using the wrong curl binary from gradle?

Tags: windows, gradle, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-bash

I have a Windows Jenkins agent where a job is invoking the curl command from gradle.

The build agent has two different curl binaries, the one included in Windows at
`C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe`
and the one included in Git for Windows at
`/mingw64/bin/curl`, which translates to `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\curl.exe`.

If I look at the `PATH` env var I see that they come in this order:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
C:\Windows\system32
```

I.e. the Git variant of curl comes before the system32 variant of curl.

Despite this, we see that the pipeline chooses to run the system32 variant when executed like this from `build.gradle`:

```java
void runCommandAndGetConsoleOutput(String command) {
    def workingDir = new File("$project.projectDir") 
    def list = []
    Process proc = command.execute(list,workingDir)
    def stdout = new StringBuffer()
    def stderr = new StringBuffer()
    proc.consumeProcessOutput(stdout, stderr)
    proc.waitFor()
    if (stdout.toString().trim()) {
        println stdout
    }
    if (stderr.toString().trim()) {
        println stderr
    }
    def exitcode = proc.exitValue()
    if (exitcode != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("'${command}' failed with exit code ${exitcode}")
    }
    return String.valueOf(stdout + stderr)
}

runCommandAndGetConsoleOutput("curl -V")
```

Output

```
curl 8.0.1 (Windows) libcurl/8.0.1 Schannel WinIDN
Release-Date: 2023-03-20
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HSTS HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI threadsafe Unicode UnixSockets
```

I cannot figure out why Gradle is using the system32 variant when it clearly is after the Git variant in the PATH. Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on here?